# excel to count the duplicate in a column

Tags: excel

I need to find the duplicates in this way.please help me

```
--|-----|-------|-------|-------|-------    
  |  A  |   B   |   C   |   D   |   E  |
--|-----|-------|-------|-------|------|    
1 | 1   |  a1   |   1   |       |      |
2 | 2   |  a2   |   1   |       |      |
3 | 3   |  a3   |   1   |       |      |
4 | 4   |  a5   |   1   |       |      |
5 | 5   |  a1   |   2   |       |      |
6 | 6   |  a2   |   2   |       |      |
7 | 7   |  a1   |   3   |       |      |
8 | 8   |  a3   |   2   |       |      |
9 | 9   |  a1   |   4   |       |      |
10| 10  |  a1   |   5   |       |      |
----------------------------------------
```

For ex: Individual duplicate B column- In B column "a1" - 5 duplicate values totally,
check the c column i need the output like that

Comment: Please elaborate. What do you mean by "duplicates"? Duplicates by all columns together or individually?

Comment: You want a cumulative sum of the number of times "a1" appeared in column B, shown in column C. Is that correctly understood?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using this formula in `Column C`

`=COUNTIF($B$1:$B1,B1)`

Let me know if it does not work.

Comment: @MathanBabu Please upvote and mark the answer as correct if you found this useful. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

You want a cumulative sum of the number of occurences of the value in column B. You can do that by inserting the following formula in **C2**:

```
=COUNTIF("$A$2:A2; A2)
```

You then drag in vertically, as far as you like. The result should be something like this:

```
  |           "C"
2 | =COUNTIF("$A$2:A2; A2)
3 | =COUNTIF("$A$2:A3; A3)
4 | =COUNTIF("$A$2:A4; A4)
```

And so on, and so on...

Comment: what about the counts for "a2" "a3" and so on?

Comment: You would have to do the same in columns "D" and "E", but with "a2" and "a3" as the second argument...

Comment: But looks like the counts should be in column C only. Please take a look at the question

Comment: I think I understand what you mean now. I edited my answer accordingly...

Answer (score 0):

In column C kindly enter below formula.

=COUNTIF($C$1:C1,C1)

And drag it to last cell c10

Regards
Lalit.M